# l3regex: skipping math formulas when matching and replacing

Tags: math-mode, l3regex

Is it possible to somehow skip math formulas when doing regex matching and replacing?

For example, in the following code, a command `\ProcessText` is defined to convert text surrounding by `*` to markups, as with in Markdown. However, for `*` in math mode, this may lead to error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \ProcessText { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \*\*\* (.*?) \*\*\* }
      { \c{textbf} { \c{emph} {\1} } }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \*\* (.*?) \*\* }
      { \c{textbf} {\1} }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \* (.*?) \* }
      { \c{emph} {\1} }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ProcessText{Text with *emphasize*, **bold** and ***both***.}

\ProcessText{Text with equation $a^{*}b^{*}$.}

\ProcessText{Text with equation \( a^{*}b^{*} \).}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple solution, check if you are in mathmode and then call your regex, skip otherwise. There are many other cases that can break the code, like sometimes end of sections I mark with  ******. Stay with LuaLaTeX and use lpeg for parsing. You can make a full marktown parser.  Also if at a point you decide you want to mke all your bold  text into something it will be a nightmare to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using 3 times `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, a solution is to use `\regex_replace_case_all:nN` and first search for the regex `\$ (.*?) \$`, then `\c{\(} (.*?) \c{\)}` and thereafter the regexes with the stars.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \ProcessText } { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_case_all:nN
      {
        { \$ (.*?) \$ } { \0 }
        { \c{\(} (.*?) \c{\)} } { \0 }
        { \*\*\* (.*?) \*\*\* } { \c{textbf} { \c{emph} { \1 } } }
        { \*\* (.*?) \*\* } { \c{textbf} { \1 } }
        { \* (.*?) \* } { \c{emph} { \1 } }
      } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ProcessText{Text with *emphasize*, **bold** and ***both***.}

\ProcessText{Text with equation $a^{*}b^{*}$.}

\ProcessText{Text with equation \( a^{*}b^{*} \).}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for this elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses only plain TeX and TeX primitives.
The main idea is that `*` is replaced by `\a`, `**` by `\aa` and `***` by `\aaa`. Moreover, `\a` is redefined in math mode using `\everymath`.

```
\def\ProcessText#1{\def\out{}\ptA#1*\end}
\def\ptA#1*{\addto\out{#1}\futurelet\next\ptB}
\def\ptB{\ifx\next\end \ea\ptZ \else
    \ifx\next*\ea\ea\ea\ptC 
    \else \addto\out{\a}\ea\ea\ea \ptA
    \fi\fi
}
\def\ptC*{\futurelet\next\ptD}
\def\ptD{\ifx\next*\ea\ptE \else \addto\out{\aa}\ea\ptA\fi}
\def\ptE*{\addto\out{\aaa}\ptA}
\def\ptZ\end{\out}

\def\a#1\a{{\it#1}}
\def\aa#1\aa{{\bf#1}}
\def\aaa#1\aaa{{\bi#1}}
\everymath{\let\a=*}

\def\addto#1#2{\ea\def\ea#1\ea{#1#2}}
\let\ea=\expandafter
\font\bi=cmbxti10

% test:

\ProcessText{Text with *emphasize*, **bold** and ***both***.}

\ProcessText{Text with equation $a^*b^*$.}

\bye
```